# Rails: multi find out if a category has members with a single fast query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

Given the model:

- `Member` -> `belongs_to :category`
- `Category` -> `has_many :members`

I would like to know for every category whether or not it has members, in the style of:

```
----------------------
| name | has_members |
======================
| cat1 | true        |
| cat2 | false       |
| cat3 | true        |
----------------------
```

The following solutions are way too slow to achieve this:

- `Category.eager_load(:members).map{|s| s.members.any?}`
- `Category.includes(:members).map{|s| s.members.any?}`

This would be a use case for a counter cache, but I wonder whether this could be solved by some smart ARel or SQL.

What would be the fastest way to achieve this?

Comment: If it comes to things like counting, especially with large data, I would always default to SQL since the DB is designed to do certain things far faster than Rails. If you don't want a counter cache, can you live with an actual count instead of true/false?

Comment: Yes, or even an integer, both would be perfectly acceptable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

What if you inverse the problem like this :

```
Member.includes(:category).order(:category_id).distinct.map{ |m| m.category !=nil ? m.category.name : "" }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is too slow as well. The resulting query is still `SELECT categories.* FROM categories WHERE categories.id IN (1,2,3,...)` with 1,2,3,... being a huge list.

Answer (score 0):

This query should return a hash of values with the name and the count of members.

```
Category.includes(:members).distinct.select('categories.name, COUNT(members.*)').group('category.name').count(:members)
#=> {"cat1"=>1,
 "cat2"=>1,
 "cat3"=>0,
 "cat4"=>2,...}
```

If you wanted JUST the Categories that have more than zero members you can do:

```
Category.joins(:members).distinct.select('categories.name, COUNT(members.*)').group('category.name').count(:members)
#=> {"cat1"=>1,
 "cat2"=>1,
 "cat4"=>2,...}
```

Which will ignore the Categories where members = 0.

The query itself is probably not what's slowing you down, it's the fact that you then pass them all to `.map` which is a ruby method, not SQL. I think for anything faster than what I've given you, you'll have to go straight to the DB with a counter cache. Also in a pure SQL query you could add a `CASE` statement to swap true/false for numbers > or < 0.

Comment: Also you give no parameters for "slow". You should be more specific with benchmark times and what you expect. Don't just look at the SQL that the rails query is producing. Have you benchmarked your queries at all?

Comment: This is the most promising answer! It takes about 350ms, whereas my attempt above was several minutes, which I meant by slow. Would you mind editing it, as it's not currently working for Rails 7.0? My suggestion that works in the lab is: `Category.joins(:members).distinct.select('category.id, COUNT(members.id)'.group('categories.id').count('members.id')`

Comment: I just realized I had "categorys" instead of "categories". I corrected that. Is that what you are talking about? Any time you type the words "not working" you NEED to tell us what exactly "not working" means, any errors etc. "not working" is completely unhelpful and will get ignored many times.

Comment: True that. The error message was that `members` was not found. I believe it was due to `count(:members)`.